# Entering directories where names match on a substring

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

I want to enter several directories in a for loop. I do not have the complete name of the directories, only a part of it.

I would like to do something like what you would write on the terminal, something like `cd *IncompleteDirName*`

This is a MVE of the loop: `IncompleteDirName`'s are obtained from the file `IncompleteDirNames`.

```
cont=1
sum=1
while read anotherFILE; do

        IncompleteDirName=$(sed "${cont}q;d" IncompleteDirNames)

        cd *"${IncompleteDirName}"*
        #  Do stuff
        cd ..
        cont=$((cont + sum))
done <anotherFILE
```

This is not working, I don't know if this has to do with wildcard not expanding or with variable not working properly.

It is throwing me this error message:

> *: No such file or directory

I suppose this means asterisk is not working as intended. It is not entering the directories, and there is a directory that matches every pattern. Anyway, no directory is being entered.

This is how `IncompleteDirNames` file looks like:

```
Alicante
Almeria 
Andalucia 
Avila
```

It is a column of names.
These are the directory names corresponding to the `IncompleteDirName`s above:

```
aa4fas_Alicante_com
mun_Almeria
comunidadde_Andalucia
ciuAvila
```

Comment: There are spaces in your IncompleteDirNames files (after "Andalucia" and "Avila"). If `*<something>*` does not match any filename, the stars `*` are interpreted litteraly so you end up doing  `cd '*Andalucia *'` which fails.

Comment: after "Almeria"* and "Andalucia", sorry.

Comment: Can you add `set -x` at the beginning of the script and post the output in your question? This would let us see what your script is actually doing.

Comment: The error message you post is incomplete. Also to feed a while loop with `<anotherfile` and on the same time use the same as a  variable name (`while read -r anotherfile`) could get you in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

That part of the script definitely works which you can easily find out by executing this test script:

```
#/bin/sh
cd
IncompleteDirName="ment"
cd *"${IncompleteDirName}"*
date > testFile
```

The first line is the shebang. The second line switches to your home directory. There should be a folder called `Documents`. The third line defines the variable `IncompleteDirName` as a substring of `Documents`. The fourth line is copied from your script. The fifth line writes the current data to the file `testFile` in the current location.

You will see a file `testFile` appear in your `Documents` folder.

The problem likely is something different in your script as Rakesh Sharma already pointed out in his answer or how you use it. I think these are likely scenarios:

- There are characters which look alike or even the same. For example, `Α` is a capital alpha, not a Latin `A`. If you search for `A` on this page and highlight all results, `A` will be highlighted but `Α` will not. Similarly, there might not be a match because what you think of as a substring of a directory's name isn't actually a substring of that directory's name.
- Capitalization matters. If you come from the Windows world, capitalization doesn't matter. You can have a directory called `A` and `cd a` (or whatever the Windows equivalent is) will get you into that directory. On the downside, having a directory called `A` on a Windows system means that you can't have a directory called `a` in the same directory. On a Unix system, this doesn't apply. `cd ~/documents` will probably fail on your machine (unless you actually have a directory called `documents` in your home folder) because the first letter isn't capitalized.

But as you can see from my example script, that part of the script definitely works.